# How can i use a local variable inside a loop outside the loop also?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables

I am a total beginner and I was trying to create a simple program that calculates the distance when speed and time and input. How can I use the unit variable outside the loop as a string? whenever I try, I get an error saying that the variable was not declared

```
speed = input("Enter the speed without the unit : ")

unit_speed = input("Which unit is the speed in? ( miles/hr or kilometres/hr) : ")

if unit_speed == "miles/hr " or unit_speed == "miles / hr" or unit_speed == "m/hr":
    unit = " miles"

elif unit_speed == "kilometres/hr " or unit_speed == "kilometres / hr" or unit_speed == "km/hr":
    unit = " kilometres"

time_hours = input("Enter the number of hours taken : ")

time_minutes = input("Enter the number of minutes taken : ")

time = int(time_hours) + int(time_minutes) / 60

print("The required distance is " + str(float(speed)*float(time)) + unit)
```

I would really appreciate any help.

BTW I am programming in python 3.

Comment: 1) I see no loop, 2) loops don't create a scope in Python anyway

Comment: declare an empty string outside condition like unit = " " so, it will be updated after if condition.

Comment: You would do well to say what variable you are unable to use and where. Along with what loop you are talking about.

Comment: I would make numeric options: (1) miles / hour (2) kilometres / hour. Less potential for typos and thus only one thing you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

### First

Your current issue has nothing to do with loops.  Your issue is from you `if` statement section of your code.

### Issue

Your actual issue was that whenever the `if` statement section was executed it didn't have a way to catch any unexpected user input, eg. if the user just typed in miles, currently the program would just crash, which was your issue.

### Solution

For the sake of this solution I have just simplified the units to either miles or kilometres.  This will check if the user has inputed something other than `miles` or `kilometres`, which are in a list, then quit the program saying invalid unit of speed.

```
if unit not in ["miles", "kilometres"]:
    print("invalid unit of speed")
    quit()
```

Also instead of having a `unit_speed` and `unit` variable, simplify it and have it in one variable, I just called it unit.

```
unit = input("Which unit is the speed in? (miles or kilometres) : ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is at your **if statement**. You need to handle execution by using else block also.

```
if unit_speed == "miles/hr " or unit_speed == "miles / hr" or unit_speed == "m/hr":
    unit = " miles"

elif unit_speed == "kilometres/hr " or unit_speed == "kilometres / hr" or unit_speed == "km/hr":
    unit = " kilometres"

else:
    # Raise exception or print output message to enter correct input here and break the excecution.
```